# Socket.io connects and disconnects immediately, and proceeds to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, connection

```js
const socketConnection = io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`Player ${socket.id} has connected to the server`);
  io.emit('displayServerChatMessage', "A New Player has joined")
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Player ${socket.id} has disconnected from the server`);
  });
});
```

This is the very **basic** code.
Now, whats wrong?


Let's say that I have a client that connects to my server. My Server (I'll call it **X**) receives and handles the connection, and logs the message. Then, just a few milliseconds later, X receives the **disconnect** event and logs "Disconnect"
The Thing is, the client (**Y**) isn't actually disconnected. I'll show that later in the post. And the even bigger thing is that Y can **send and receive data** just as it would normally, and when Y actually disconnects, there is no disconnect message.

Now, how can I say that Y hasn't disconnected?

```js
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to server');

    socket.emit('playerJoinDataToServer', {name: getCookie('playerName'), id: socket.id})
});

socket.on('displayChatMessage', (data) => {
  let history = document.getElementById('chat-history')
  history.innerHTML += `<p style='margin:3px;'>${data}</p>`; // This is weak to an Injection attack, but that's not important right now.
  console.log('Received message:', data);
});
socket.on('displayServerChatMessage', (data) => {
  let history = document.getElementById('chat-history')
  history.innerHTML += `<p style='margin:3px;color:red;'>${data}</p>`;
  console.log('Received message:', data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Disconnected from server');
});
```

This Code, my client-side code, Logs that it is connected, and it received the "New Player joined" message. But it never logged that it disconnected in the first few seconds when X thinks Y has disconnected. When it does disconnect, and log the message, **X doesn't receive any disconnect message** and, that's bad?

So how can this *problem* be solved?